# How do I know if fbAudienceNetwork really works?

Tags: xcode, facebook-audience-network

I have set up the code in `Xcode` and use `FBAdSettings.addTestDevice` to run it in the simulator with test ads. It works fine. But how Do I know if the real ad works? As far as I can tell there is no way to run the real ads in simulator or on device. I have a placement ID for the real ad, and all code is in place. But there doesn't seem to be a way to actually see if it works... unless I upload the ap.